# Azure Service Fabric Deployment through VS 2017 publish stuck with status Copying application to image store

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-service-fabric

I created an app as mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-create-dotnet-app

I was able to deploy to local cluster to see this application live. Then I removed the local cluster to publish through VS 2017 to Azure Service Fabric. But output windows seems struck after a message "Copying application to image store..."

I am using the latest ASF SDK for this development, and the OS is Windows 10 Enterprise. Any lead towards further investigation would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this could help you.https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/813#issuecomment-363271279

Comment: It was talking about removing local cluster, which i already done.

Comment: I have ran through the doc but am not seeing any issues. Seems something with your local cluster is the issue. You might try setting up the cluster first instead of letting visual studio do it for you. Just open Service Fabric Manager and create a new cluster. Once you confirm it is running publish the app and see if it works

Comment: Check the status of the local cluster and see how far along the deployment has gotten (e.g. still copying or stuck trying to bring up the service). To try a deployment outside of VS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started-with-a-local-cluster